# Interpreting percentage units and a rate per 1000 in a regression

Tags: linear-regression, estimation, coefficients

I want to examine the effect of the crime rate on school performance.

My dependent variable is the percentage of students who secure the 80 percentile or above of the grades,

and the crime rate is calculated per 1,000 students.

Therefore, my estimation model becomes as:

% of student=a+ b* crime rate + error.

If the estimate of b is -1.16, how can I interpret the result?